# What's the best way to create your own website?

Tags: web-development, web-services

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the best way to create your own website?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/23541/whats-the-best-way-to-create-your-own-website)

I'm currently making plans for creating my own website (.com) and was looking for the cheapest solution possible that gives you the production tools you need.

I was wondering, are most websites these days made by "website wizards" or whatever they are called, that you just configure and tweak, or do most websites involve a lot of programming? (I am currently a CS major but need to budget my time so website providers that give you a lot of flexibility and control over how your site works, but minimizes programming would probably be the best solution).

I'm basically looking for the most direct way to establish my own website with its own domain name. Probably the most complex service it will need to provide is that (privileged) visitors with an account/password to my website should be able to edit the webpages. There will also be a need to make this visually appealing.

Any tips out there are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Just use one of the many blogging platforms.

Comment: There's no one-size-fits-all "best" solution for creating a website. Each website owner's needs and objectives are different. You should specify what type of site it will be, not just describe a single feature that you think is "the most complex". Is this going to be a blog-style site where people make chronologically-ordered posts? Is this going to be a wiki? What is the purpose of the site?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest going with one of the better known hosting providers, and then just using the default WordPress installation.  I [use HostGator](http://secure.hostgator.com/~affiliat/cgi-bin/affiliates/clickthru.cgi?id=kaalkop) and have not had better service from anyone else.